# Android daily notifications do not work properly

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-broadcast, android-alarms

I want to display notification every morning at 9 AM from my app.

So I am using Notification Manager, Alarm Manager, BroadcastReciever and Service to make that possible.

But I have a problem, because the notification shows randomly. When I first start the app and set the time, it works OK, but later the app fires and shows notification at random time.

How I can solve that?

Here is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setAlarm();
}

public void setAlarm(){


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();


    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 43);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if(calendar.getTime().after(now.getTime())) {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HoroscopeNotification.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);        }

 }
```

**HoroscopNotification (BroadcastReciever)**

```
public class HoroscopeNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        showNotification(context);
    }

    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
    }
}
```

**AlarmService**

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
         return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Horoskop");
        builder.setContentText("Pročitajte današnji horoskop");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_bik);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add logs to see what is the calendar actually being registered as. That will give you a clear indication of what is actually be registered and when EXACTLY it should fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice in the Android SDK Reference material for the [`AlarmManager.setRepeating()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) states:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose `targetSdkVersion` is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

You need to use [`AlarmManager.set()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) on pre-APIv19 and [`AlarmManager.setExact()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) on APIv19+. When your `PendingIntent` is fired and you receive your Broadcast in your `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` you can set another exact alarm for the next day.

Comment: Should I set alarm on activity first or somewhere else?

Comment: Hey, where do I initially need to set alarm?

Comment: Yes. When the user launches your app. So yes your MainActivity.

Comment: Just when he starts the app for the first time? And then on BroadcastReciever should set notification for the next day.

Comment: Yes. It might be good to then set the methods to static and move them into a new class called DailyAlarm or something l. For organisation and clarity of code.

Comment: Just to be clear eveytime MainActivity loads it should see if a alarm has been set and if not, set one.

Comment: I have added app launch counter and save it to SharedPrefs, and if it is first launch, then I initially set the alarm. And after alarms fires then I set next alarm. Is there logic to check if alarm is active?

Comment: Yes, you can. Read the PendingIntent documentation.

Comment: Will do, but I think that this should work OK with app counter approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88087/discussion-between-simon-and-zookey).

Comment: if it's working then please share with us also.

Answer (score 0):

[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

I think you should follow above link. From my point of view, your design pattern (setting alarm in `Activity` class is not a good approach). Instead (like showed in the answer above) you should set your alarm from a service. Also the code for notification goes in `BroadcastReceiver` class, method `OnReceive` (In the example it is commented "Put here YOUR code").

Good luck